# Implement Heap Sort using sift down approach in c

Tags: c, sorting, heap

I'm trying to implement heap sort using sift down approach in c, The output of the program is missing 0th index of the array. I'm unable to find the issue where the problem is, Is it due to array overflow?

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void heapSort(int[], int);
void siftdown(int[], int, int, int);
int main(void)
{
     int array[] = {5, 2, 1, 4, 3};
   int nodeCount = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
     heapSort(array, nodeCount);
     printf("Sorted array:\n");

      for(int i=0; i < nodeCount; i++)
        {
           printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        }
     return 0;
}
void heapSort(int array[], int nodeCount){
     //creating a heap
     for(int i = nodeCount / 2; i >= 1; i--){
         siftdown(array, array[i], i, nodeCount);
     }

     //perform heapsort
     for(int lastNode = nodeCount; lastNode > 1; lastNode--){
         int lastNodeValue = array[lastNode];
         array[lastNode] = array[1];
         array[1] = lastNodeValue;
         siftdown(array, lastNodeValue, 1, lastNode -1);
     }
}
void siftdown(int array[], int nodeValue, int root, int last){
     int leftChild = 2 * root + 1 ;
     while(leftChild <= last){ //at least has one child
         if(leftChild < last){ //has right child
             if(array[leftChild + 1] > array[leftChild]){
                 leftChild++;
             }
        }
         if(nodeValue >= array[leftChild]){
             break;
         }
         else{
             array[root] = array[leftChild];
             root = leftChild;
            leftChild = 2 * root + 1;
         }
         array[root] = nodeValue;
     }
}
```

The output of the program:

> Sorted array: 5 1 2 3 4

Comment: You are passing 1 to `siftdown` as the start of the array, so it is ignoring element 0.

Comment: @DougCurrie - I have corrected the loop but still the problem is there - https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/CUMtWaletT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop in your `heapSort` function is:

```
 for(int i = nodeCount / 2; i >= 1; i--){
     siftdown(array, array[i], i, nodeCount);
 }
```

Because `i` is never 0, you don't ever sift that node down. Change the comparison to `i >= 0`.

In your `heapSort` function, you have this loop:

```
 //perform heapsort
 for(int lastNode = nodeCount; lastNode > 1; lastNode--){
     int lastNodeValue = array[lastNode];
     array[lastNode] = array[1];
     array[1] = lastNodeValue;
     siftdown(array, lastNodeValue, 1, lastNode -1);
 }
```

Arrays in C start at 0. So if you have 5 items in the array, the indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Your loop is using array indexes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. You need to change that loop as well. It will look something like:

```
 //perform heapsort
 for(int lastNode = nodeCount-1; lastNode > 0; lastNode--){
     int lastNodeValue = array[lastNode];
     array[lastNode] = array[0];
     array[0] = lastNodeValue;
     siftdown(array, lastNodeValue, 0, lastNode-1);
 }
```

Comment: Didn't worked, array is getting overflowed somehow https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/CUMtWaletT

Comment: @SanjeetPalSingh Why are you linking to that code? Is that the code you want me to look at, or do you want me to look at the code you posted in the question?